# How to find number of days between two unix timestamps in java

Tags: java, timestamp

I am using unix timestamp to store the purchase date in my application. 
sample data: 1371463066

I want to do some manipulation based on the difference in number of days and current day timestamp.
for example: If the number of days between the purchase date and current date is 5 days, then send an email regarding feedback again.

how to get the difference in days between two timestamps using java?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have not tested it but you may try to do something like this:

```
Date purchasedDate = new Date ();
//multiply the timestampt with 1000 as java expects the time in milliseconds
purchasedDate.setTime((long)purchasedtime*1000);

Date currentDate = new Date ();
currentDate .setTime((long)currentTime*1000);

//To calculate the days difference between two dates 
int diffInDays = (int)( (currentDate.getTime() - purchasedDate.getTime()) 
                 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) )
```

Comment: does (currenttime - purchacedtime)/24*60*60 not work ?

Answer (score 3):

Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1.1.1970. If you have 2 unix timestamps then the difference in full days is

int diff = (ts1 - ts2) / 3600 / 24

Comment: I do not think this would account for leap years

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Calendars (which will also allow you to use TimeZones):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1371427200l * 1000l);
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
newCalendar.setTimeInMillis(1371527200l * 1000l);
// prints the difference in days between newCalendar and calendar
System.out.println(newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: what if second date has different year?

Comment: Ah yes I stupidly assumed it would be the same year, don't know why. In that case instead of comparing the DAY_OF_YEAR values, you'd need to compare the time stamps, pretty much like Juned Ashad does in his/her answer. You can still do that from Calendar though.